# How do Amiga "Monitor" drivers work?

Tags: amiga, video

A "Monitor" driver for an Amiga is a file which, when placed in DEVS:Monitors, enables additional screenmodes. The standard PAL or NTSC driver, which provides screenmodes compatible with consumer TV frequencies, is built-in to the OS, but by adding further drivers, additional screenmodes become available. For example, adding the Multiscan monitor driver adds the "Productivity" screenmodes that are a higher resolution (640x480) and higher scan rate (closer to the PC VGA standard) but which require a compatible monitor to be used.

How do these drivers work? How are they made?

They appear to be executable files that are simply run during startup. Therefore I assume that they execute some code which calls into the OS to add the new screenmodes to an in-memory table. How do they do this - where are screenmodes stored in the OS? Why are they executable rather than just a static data structure that the OS could load and parse?

To put the question another way - say I've invented a new monitor which only accepts video frequencies that are not supported by any of the existing drivers, and I want to create a monitor driver for it. How do I do that?

Comment: Windows monitor drivers were actually just a text file a containing monitor timings.

Comment: @RossRidge much like xorg.conf files on Unix systems I guess. I'd have thought the Amiga had a similar sort of thing..

Comment: FWIW: in a Linux environment I would use `strace` (or even `ltrace`) to see what a program is doing. I don't know if programs like [DOSTrace](http://aminet.net/package/util/moni/DOSTrace213 "Aminet - util/moni/DOSTrace213.lha") cover library calls or only filesystem access. They might provide a hint?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Amiga `.monitor` files follow the same conventions as Exec Device Drivers. They are loadable shared libraries. Instead of providing an Open/CloseDevice interface, they provide Open/CloseMonitor. `OpenMonitor()` can be called to get the `MonitorSpec` data structure that defines the monitor's capabilities. This information then becomes part of the Amiga graphics.library `DisplayInfo` database that is used by applications to query and setup different display modes.

At boot, AmigaOS scans DEVS: for various disk-based (as opposed to ROM-based) device drivers (i.e. shared libraries). DEVS:Monitors is just the sub-directory where `.monitor` device drivers live. So AmigaOS can add them to the `DisplayInfo` database and then make all the supported display modes visisble for the user to choose in the Preferences app. The common `.monitor` drivers (NTSC, PAL) are present in ROM, so DEVS:Monitors is really just for specifying non-standard monitors that extend the available display modes.

Comment: I thought this was pretty interesting, so I went and took a look in my library for more information re: Open/CloseMonitor() - there is a good deal of information in the Amiga ROM Kernel Reference Manual (v3) - Libraries; in the section "Monitors Modes, and the Display Database" (approx. page 518 in my PDF).